# What is "HyperConvergence"

Tags: networking

When I searched for the "*HyperConvergence*" ..I got something like this..

> *Hyper-convergence (hyperconvergence) is a type of infrastructure system with a software-centric architecture that tightly integrates compute, storage, networking and virtualization resources and other technologies from scratch in a commodity hardware box supported by a single vendor.*<sup>[1](http://searchconvergedinfrastructure.techtarget.com/definition/hyper-convergence)</sup>

but I didn't get the exact meaning of it. Can someone make the point clear and simple terms?

*Moreover, I could not find which tag to attach in this regard so I added **networking***.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://searchconvergedinfrastructure.techtarget.com/definition/hyper-convergence</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-convergence is a type of infrastructure system with a software architecture that integrates compute, storage, networking and virtualization resources and other technologies from scratch, given by a single vendor.

Good examples for these infrastructures, that you might have heard of may be Hitachi, Stratoscale symphony, Cisco systems and more.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper Convergence is a system that manages all IT components related to a firm using a software layer .
it includes integrating IT related components like computing , storage , networking resources.